# How can I make an unallocated SD partition usable?

Tags: mount

When I plugin my SD card, my Ubuntu 13.04 doesn't list it. But when I check it from the terminal using the `ls` command by `/dev/sd*` it shows the device, but still remains unmounted.

I formatted it using the DISKPART command in Windows.
How can I make this unmounted space to a usable form?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Nikhil! What's the output of the command `sudo fdisk -l`? You can [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sd is not mounted automatically you can mount it using the `mount` command through the terminal just make sure `fdisk -l` lists the sd.

First format it using the command

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdname
```

Then mount it using the command

```
mount /dev/sdname /directory/to/mount/sd
```

If you want to mount it permanently then give the entry in the file,

```
cat /etc/fstab
```

Add the line

```
/dev/sd place/to/mount ext4 defaults 0 0
```

If the sd is NTFS or FAT format go to the link below

[Mount NTFS or FAT filesystem](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mounting-windows-partition-onto-ubuntu-linux/)